# Creating React component for distribution results in much larger build than expected

Tags: reactjs, requirejs, webpack, umd

I've loosely followed [this link](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/distributing-react-components-babel-browserify-webpack-uglifyjs) to create my react components for distribution. My webpack production build is below.

However my build comes out much larger than I would expect it to considering that the individual file sizes combined are somewhere around 1/10th the size. Specifically my file sizes for the source js and less files, combined is only 1.6kb. However the build is ~10x more at 13kb.

My components are extremely simple and similar. I have a FlexTable, a FlexTableRow and a FlexTableCell file. All of them have the same signature as below but with a different `style.less`. In my `style.less` it is basically a few lines of css that say `display: flex; flex: 0` etc etc. So to summarize, very minimal js and very minimal amounts of css.

So the question is, why does the production build balloon to 13kb from 1.6kb? What am I doing wrong?

my-flex-table.js

```
var React = require('react');

const styles = require('./my-flex-table.less')

const FlexTable = (props) => (
  <section {...props} className={styles['my-flex-table'] + " " + props.customStyles}>{props.children}</section>
)

module.exports = FlexTable;
```

(Replace FlexTable with FlexTableRow or FlexTableCell in the above and you have my other files)

My `package.json` points to an index file that simply exports all 3 of these with module.exports = {FlexTable, FlexTableCell, FlexTableRow}

The webpack production script is run with:

`NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.prod.js`

Webpack production script

```
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var postcssImport = require('postcss-import');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: './dist/my-flex-table.js',
    library: 'MyFlexTable',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.less']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
          presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0','react']
        },
        "env": {
          "production": {
            "presets": ["react-optimize"]
          }
        }
      },
      { test: /.less$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss-loader!less-loader' },
      { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
    ]
  },
  postcss: function (wp) {
      return [postcssImport({
                addDependencyTo: wp
      }),autoprefixer];
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        unused: true,
        dead_code: true,
        drop_console: true,
        warnings: false
      }
    })

  ],
  externals: [
    {
      react: {
        root: 'React',
        commonjs2: 'react',
        commonjs: 'react',
        amd: 'react',
      },
    },
    {
      'react-dom': {
        root: 'ReactDOM',
        commonjs2: 'react-dom',
        commonjs: 'react-dom',
        amd: 'react-dom',
      },
    },
  ]
};
```

Comment: Turn off Uglify and look at the source of the output files. It's either react itself getting bundled in there, or babel's runtime is 10kb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [webpack visualizer](https://chrisbateman.github.io/webpack-visualizer/) is a good tool to troubleshoot bundle sizes. Follow the instructions there and it might help you see what extra is getting bundled in that you might not be intending.

Comment: Accepting this answer, but should mention that Andy Ray's comment was the one that showed me babel's runtime was adding 6-7kb. This answer was useful for me to confirm that nothing else was added.